# How to set thumbnail to imported WordPress posts in bulk

Tags: php, python, wordpress, scrapy

I scrape data from a website and store it into an XML file (using python). While downloading images from other website and storing them into my WordPress site, the WordPress assign them a unique ID which I don't know. So I can't assign that image as a thumbnail to my scraped posts. I can't edit posts one by one because they are in bulk. Is there any other solution?

I can display images on posts but I need to know the ID to assign them as a thumbnail. I also used plugins which auto assign the first image as a thumbnail but they also require image ID...

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40301/how-do-i-set-a-featured-image-thumbnail-by-image-url-when-using-wp-insert-post). You need to use a variety of built-in WordPress functions for this:

```
wp_insert_attachment()
set_post_thumbnail()
wp_generate_attachment_metadata()
wp_update_attachment_metadata()
```

`wp_insert_attachment()` is probably your most important function as it returns your attachment (image) ID. `set_post_thumbnail()` then takes this attachment ID and your post ID to set the image as the featured image in the post.

When I've done this in the past I also found that I had to use the metadata functions above to correctly assign the image which was for removing posts from an import *and* their associated images.

```
        file_put_contents($oldfile, $image_data);
        rename( $oldfile, $newfile );

        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $newfile, $post_id );
        
        if ( $set_thumb ) {
            $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
        }

        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $newfile );
        $update_attach_metadata = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```